# Asp.Net HttpPostedFile.SaveAs fails: access is denied

Tags: asp.net, access-denied, httppostedfile

In my ASP.NET web application, I am trying to upload a file using JQuery Ajax which in turn calls `.ashx handler`. Files should be saved to `pdf` folder which is created under the project's tree using:

> Add --> New Folder

When deployed and tested, SaveAs fails with `access is denied` error.

All solutions on the internet suggest editing permissions on the folder. So on server, I granted `Network Service` user full control over `pdf` folder, and **upload worked** then... but the problem is that **any subsequent deployement of  the web application just removes those permissions on server** and the problem returns, of course.

I gave full control to `Network Service` over `Inetpub` folder to overcome that problem, and that solved the case. But is it acceptable to do that?

It feels wrong, so please, what do you suggest to solve the problem instead of my workaround?

Code in handler is as following:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   try
   {
       if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
       {
           HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];

           string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/pdf");

           string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
           postedFile.SaveAs( Path.Combine(filePath , fileName) );

           string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                     new { name = fileName });

           context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
           context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
           context.Response.Write(json);
           context.Response.End();
        }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text";
            context.Response.Write(e.Message);
            context.Response.End();
    }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try give the permission to that folder IIS_USR with full control .It will work. We have to provide the IIS user not network service account.

Comment: same issue! when website is deployed again later after any modification, permissions to IIS_USR  will vanish, and need to be added manually again !

Comment: Try one more thing, Website apppool mention the Identity as one windows account instead of network service. It will be accessible. These are only two options i have fixed in my previous project the same issue.

Comment: Identity is "NetworkService"...
The problem is not the user... the problem is that permissions have to be set manually after each deployment for the website